# How do I access sibling controls of a HyperlinkButton sender in the click event in VB for WP7?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone

In a WP7 app I'm building, I have a `HyperlinkButton` used to show a clickable phone number:

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding ContactPhoneNumber}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="PhoneLink_Click" />
```

Before that, there is a `TextBlock` with the name:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ContactName}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
    Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
```

Needless to say, these are all in a data-bound `<ListBox>`. Also, the phone calling task works just fine.

The `PhoneLink_Click` handler is able to access the `Content` property (after `DirectCast`ing), but how do I access the `Text` property of the preceding `<TextBlock>`?

I'm new to WP7 and this is my 2nd app.

Answer (score 0):

If the `HyperlinkButton` is part of a `DataTemplate` for a ListBox, you shouldn't use the `Click` event, but instead use the `ListBox.SelectionChanged` event.

That way, you'll get the bound item (from the `SelectedItem` property), which gives you access to both the `ContactName` and the `ContactPhoneNumber`.